# Can I attach a Thunderbolt-to-Firewire adapter and a Mini DisplayPort monitor to the same computer?

Tags: thunderbolt, firewire

I have a 2013 MacBook Air with one Mini DisplayPort/Thunderbolt 1 port. Is there a way to connect both an LED Cinema Display and my old Firewire accessories to this port?

Answer (score 4):

You need a [Thunderbolt *Dock* with a Firewire port](http://radnex.us/akitio-tb2-dock-firewire)

Thunderbolt is not like video or USB where you can get an inexpensive splitter and just multiply or split the signals.   So, to use two devices simultaneously, you need a dock.

Comment: Ugh. That's as expensive as the monitor, and does much more than I need it to—and there doesn't seem to be a cheaper option. I think I'll figure out how to connect the FireWire devices via USB. Thanks.

Comment: I know what you mean.  Thunderbolt is awesome, but it's awesomeness is directly proportional to it's price.

Comment: I picked up a OWC Thunderbolt Dock on eBay, new but no box, for a very reasonable price and quite a discount. Well worth it as I found use for many other ports including the fast charging USB ports.

Comment: Hm. That's a good idea. Unfortunately, it puts me in a quandary: If I go that route, I can't use the Henge Dock I was thinking of getting, and must instead use the LandingZone dock, because the Henge does not support Thunderbolt, just Mini DisplayPort.